# Soundcloud Triggers

Tags: soundcloud

Can SoundCloud's API be used to generate a notification for any of the following events?:

- Someone plays a track
- Someone likes a track
- Someone reposts a track
- Someone comments on a track

Comment: Please write what you have tested or done yet.

Comment: AlphaB - I haven't tested or done anything yet.  I'm not technical.  Just asking the community if they know whether or not what I'm asking is feasible.